# The meaning of "Naturally Enough"

Tags: phrases

I have been reading a book about programming and since I am not very good with the phrases, I got confused.

Please notice the following text :

> #### Modules
>
> You may think of modules as extensions that can be imported into Python to extend its capabilities.
>   You import modules with a special command called (naturally enough) import.

What is the meaning of *naturally enough*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context "naturally enough" means "as you would expect"... In other words, it seems obvious and natural that the command to Import a Module is "import" because the command word is synonymous with its function.

Comment: I understood!Thank you so much!the answer was really helpful!

Comment: One should perhaps add that this is an understatement. The writer pretends that it's not all that natural to call the import command *import*, but merely 'natural enough' (for whatever purpose). However, since *naturally enough* is almost always used in this jocular way, it has essentially become a useless longer idiom that just means *naturally*.